# how to use passport SAML with both node (express) as backend and vue as client

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, passport.js, passport-saml

I have an app with node (express) backend, and vue client.
I'm trying to add SAML SSO using passport. (makes sense to do it on the server node app).

it works perfect when used in express app. but when I applied it to a structure of express backend and vue client - it fails to make the redirection to the Idp.

when user enters my login page, vue client (Login.vue) calls node backend for verifying the user. (api verifyuser)

node call passport.authenticate('saml', ...) and I expected a response I can send back to the vue function that called me, and there, in Login.vue - to make the redirection.

but here comes the problem:
in the backend node app, the redirect response is sent after my code is executed, inside passport strategy. So it is sent automatically to the browser, not returning to the vue script that called this node api.

So the redirection is done in the background, the user don't see any redirect. the original login page is still shown.
And my vue function gets the response back from the API - only after the browser sends the redirect (in the background) to the IDP, and gets the login html page response from the IDP.
So the data I get back - is an html of the IDP login page, instead of a redirection data.

How can I solve it?

I'm new to client technologies and js and node including, so I really don't know how such a flow should be handled. searching 3 days for solution.

Thanks a lot for you assistance!

here is my snippets of code:

Login.vue:

```
<input class="button wide cropBottom io-mango ae-5 margin-top-0 toRight" v-on:click="userLogin"  type="button" value="Log In"/>
...
userLogin: function() {
      ...
      ...
        $(".overlay").show();
        this.$http.post(process.env.BASE_URL + "verifyuser", oUser)  //call backend node express app
         .then(function(data) {
               ...
               here I gets only an html login page which the IDP sent as a response to the redirect with the SAML Request.
          }
```

Backend node express app:

verifyuser.js:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.post('/verifyuser', (req, res, next) => {


      var SamlStrategy = passportSaml.Strategy;

      passport.use(new SamlStrategy(
        {  ...
        });

      passport.authenticate('saml', {session: false}, function (err, user, info) {
            ...
            })(req,res,next);


    //tried to get the redirect here, but res still don't have it. only after this function is called, the SAML request is created from the req, and the location url is made.      

     });
```

Comment: Meantime - I edited passport library.
changed authenticate.js file, function strategy.redirect.
 instead of this :

    res.statusCode = status || 302;
    res.setHeader('Location', url);
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
    res.end();


I changed it to:

    var redirectData = { statusCode: status || 302, locationUrl: url };
    res.send(redirectData);

So now it is sent to the Vue client as a data instead of a redirect response, so I can take out the location url and make the redirection myself.

But it's a bad solution of course to change original library.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.
I changed the Vue client:
instead of calling the server using ajax, and expecting a data response to come back,
I called the server using post of a form.
that way, the browser redirects to the server when I call it, and when the passport library in the server returns a redirect response- it is done in the forground, and the user can see it.

In Single logout, passport have done a better job:
the passport API just returns the logout request created.
then I can decide myself if I want redirect from the server, or I want to send the redirection request to the waiting client function - and do the redirection from there.